# por que no salta al segundo flatmap en cuanto termina el metodo del flatmap anterior?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, programación-reactiva, spring-webflux

Tengo este codigo que en el primer flatmap corre un metodo cerrarPersonasPorTraza y luego lo retorna como void junto a 2 variables, el metodo si me funciona correctamente ya lo probe desde la base de datos ya que solo actualiza unos campos, el problema es que luego de eso se queda ahi y no sigue con el siguiente flatmap, por que tambien probe con flatMapSequential y aun asi no llega ni a mostrar el mensaje que le puse para la consola. "log.info("pasando al segundo flatmap {}",nueva);"

```
.zipWith(trazabilidadDAO.findById(item.getIdTraza()))
                .flatMap(tuple -> {
                    DestinatariosRequest destinatario = tuple.getT1().getT1();
                    Traza traza = tuple.getT2();
                    Traza nuevaTraza = tuple.getT1().getT2();
                    log.info("expediente {} ", traza.getIdExpediente());
                    log.info("desti {} ", destinatario.getId());
                    return Flux.zip(
                        Mono.just(destinatario),
                        Mono.just(nuevaTraza),
                        personaPorTrazaDAO.cerrarPersonasPorTraza(
                            traza.getIdExpediente(),
                            destinatario.getId(),
                            Constantes.ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE_TERMINADO,
                            Arrays.asList(Constantes.ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE_ARCHIVADO, Constantes.ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE_TERMINADO)
                        ).doOnError(error -> {
                            log.info("Ocurrió un error en accion: " ,error.getMessage());
                        })
                    );
                })
                .flatMap(tuple -> {
                    DestinatariosRequest destinatario = tuple.getT1();
                    Traza nueva = tuple.getT2();
                    log.info("pasando al segundo flatmap {}",nueva);
                    return Flux.zip(
                        Mono.just(destinatario),
                        Mono.just(nueva),
                        personaPorTrazaDAO.save(PersonaPorTraza.builder()
                                .idPersona(destinatario.getId())
                                .traza(nueva.getId())
                                .responsable(true)
                                .bloqueado(false)
                                .leido(false)
                                .leidoReemplazo(false)
                                .idAreaDestinatario(destinatario.getIdArea())
                                .estado(Constantes.ESTADO_RECIBIDO)
                                .privado(false)
                                .observacion("Aprobado")
                                .build()
                        ).doOnError(error -> {
                            System.out.println("Ocurrió un error en ppt: " + error.getMessage());
                        })
                    );
                })
```

Comment: lo mas probable es que sea un NPE, *harcodea* y así creo que notaras cual de los campos del destinatario o nueva viene nulo.